# Laravel Relationship returning no results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a "booking" that has relationships with the "markets" and "stalls"

I have the Selects working on the create form but the index blade is not displaying correctly.

It should take the `id` and convert it to the `name` field as in the below

```
 <td>{{$user->role ? $user->role->name : 'User has no role'}}</td>
```

And this displays correctly with the following **Model** code:

```
public function role(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Role');
}
```

and this is my **"Bookings" Model**:

```
public function marketdate(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Markets');
}

public function stallstype() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Stalls');
}
```

With the following on the **index.blade**:

```
...
<td>{{$booking->marketdate ? $booking->marketdate->date : '-' }}</td>
<td>{{$booking->stallstype ? $booking->stallstype->name : '-'}}</td>
...
```

But this just shows the "-" when it renders the page

the ID's that are stored in the database are correct and do correlate it is just not displaying correctly.

One other thing, the table schemas are as follows:

**Stalls table**:

```
Schema::create('stalls', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('cost');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

**Markets table**:

```
  Schema::create('markets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->integer('is_active');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

The **error** is:

> at PhpEngine-
>
> > evaluatePath('C:\xampp\htdocs\moowoos\storage\framework\views/3bcb71b43fffee7f9
> >     a9edf18bfb397ab94380507.php', array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app'
> >     => object(Application), 'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'bookings' => object(Collection), 'markets' => array('Saturday 4th March', 'Saturday 5th April', 'Saturday 6th May', 'Saturday 7th June',
> >     'Saturday 8th July', 'Saturday 8th July'), 'stalltype' =>
> >     array('Preloved', 'Craft', 'Business'))) in compiled.php line 15361
> >         at CompilerEngine->get('C:\xampp\htdocs\moowoos\resources\views/admin/bookings/index.blade.php',
> >     array('__env' => object(Factory), 'app' => object(Application),
> >     'errors' => object(ViewErrorBag), 'bookings' => object(Collection),
> >     'markets' => array('Saturday 4th March', 'Saturday 5th April',
> >     'Saturday 6th May', 'Saturday 7th June', 'Saturday 8th July',
> >     'Saturday 8th July'), 'stalltype' => array('Preloved', 'Craft',
> >     'Business'))) in compiled.php line 15193

Which shows that it is returning the `array`

Comment: Are you sure that there is data in there?

Comment: Yes, well, I can see the IDs in the "bookings" table in the DB and those IDs do correspond with what is in the DB for the relevant tables as my dropdown on the create page uses the same relationship to populate

Comment: I'd say that you don't get any data for booking and it's always false in the result. How do you fetch your $booking object?

Comment: My create function on the controller is as follows:     $markets = Markets::lists('date','id')->all();
        $stalltype = Stalls::lists('name','id')->all();
        return view ('admin.bookings.create', compact('markets','stalltype')); and this works for the Create blade

Comment: The objects are fetched using $markets = Markets::lists('date','id')->all(); and
        $stalltype = Stalls::lists('name','id')->all(); in the Controller

Comment: How do you load bookings? If you use lists() the same way as for markets and stalltypes this could be the reason related models can't be loaded. If that's the case, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Eloquent is not able to load related models. As you use **lists()** to load your other models I assume you do the same for Business model.

When you call **lists('name', 'id')**, you're telling Eloquent to load only those 2 fields from the database. So, if you use that to load Business models as well, you're not fetching **marketdate_id** nor **stallstype_id**, that's why Eloquent is not able to load the related models.

Make sure that foreign key columns are passed to **lists()** method if you want to load related models:

```
Business::lists('name', 'id', 'stalltype_id', 'marketdate_id')->all();
```